# Как правильно проводить юнит тестирование репозитория?

Tags: php, phpunit

Дано: laravel, архитектура слоев: repository-service-controller-view.

Нужно сделать тестирование репозитория.

Задача: сделать выборку неопубликованных статей.

Проблема: чтобы проверить выборку, нужно сначала заполнить базу/репозиторий опубликованными и неопубликованными статьями. Чисто теоретически, мы не должны зависеть от источника данных: БД, API или еще что-то, для этого репозиторий и нужен. Значит нативно забить базу перед тестом - не лучшее решение (или я не прав?). Значит нужно заполнять базу репозиторием, но как то странно - при тестировании одного функционала - использовать другой, который сам может дать ошибку. Вдруг будет неправильно работать именно заполнение через репозиторий, а не выборка?

Как правильно заполнять базу перед тестом выборки из репозитория?

И обратный вопрос, как проверять базу при тестировании добавления в базу через репозиторий? Репозиторием на выборку или запросами к БД?

Для примера есть такой метод (как его тестировать?):

```
class CountryRepository
{
    public function getModel()
    {
        return new Country();
    }

    public function getWithoutCitiesById(int $id)
    {
        return $this->getModel()
            ->has('radios', '<', 1)
            ->select(['id', 'name', 'iso', 'published'])
            ->find($id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно замокать класс для работы с бд. Проверять что прилетают правильные sql-запросы и возвращать результаты, которые должны как-то повлиять на методы рпозитория.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин но репозиторий у меня грубо говоря и есть класс для работы с БД. Я тестирую его ответы. Да и внутри Элокв.... что фиг замокаешь.

Comment: Получается, что с бд работает Элоквент, а не рпозиторий. Неужели его нельзя замокать?

Comment: @ЕгорБанин слышал что с ними боль)  IgorDyshlenko ниже описал свои мысли по этому поводу

Answer (score 1):

В Laravel есть прекрасный инструмент тестирования работы с БД - [seeds](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database-testing#using-seeds). Он позволяет проводить все тесты на гарантированно одном и том же наборе данных и, соответственно, определять правильность выборки. Готовите тестовый набор сидов, пишите тесты, и каждый из них отработает на именно этом наборе. Единственный нюанс: нужно настроить соединение с БД для теста (данные в базе перезатираются при каждом тесте) в файле phpunit.xml. Деталей не помню, в доке по phpunit это есть точно. В моем случае добавлял раздел для тестирования Job'ов

```xml
<phpunit>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql_testing"/>
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="test"/>
        <env name="MAIL_DRIVER" value="log"/>
        <env name="APP_KEY" value="AckfSECXIv28GVIWUAxmbBSjTsmF"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

При таком подходе все тестирование сводится к ассертам на наличие правильных данных в ответе БД. Ну и ассерты на наличие / отсутствие данных в базе там же описаны.

Comment: Сиды - это запуск классов, в которых мы используем Элоку, либо базу. Но если мы подменим репозиторий на сторонний api, то как тогда тестировать?

Comment: Тогда - Doctrine, отделение источника данных от Репозитория, раздельное тестирование репозитория, источника и т.д. Eloquent не предоставляет возможностей подмены БД на API без "доработки напильником", а доработка будет бессмысленна. Но в вопросе стоит изначально Eloquent.

Answer (score 1):

Пока что ваш репозиторий не имеет большого смысла и юнит-тест демонстрирует это.

```
<?php

// class Country
// {

//     public function has(...$args)
//     {
//         return $this;
//     }

//     public function select(...$args)
//     {
//         return $this;
//     }

//     public function find(...$args)
//     {
//         return [];
//     }

// }

class CountryRepository
{

    private $model;

    public function __construct(Country $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function getWithoutCitiesById(int $id)
    {
        return $this->model
            ->has('radios', '<', 1)
            ->select(['id', 'name', 'iso', 'published'])
            ->find($id);
    }
}

class CountryRepositoryTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{

    public function testGetWithoutCitiesById()
    {
        $id = 123;
        $uniqId = uniqid();
        $country = $this->getMockBuilder(Country::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
        $country
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('has')
            ->with('radios', '<', 1)
            ->will($this->returnSelf());
        $country
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('select')
            ->with(['id', 'name', 'iso', 'published'])
            ->will($this->returnSelf());
        $country
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('find')
            ->with($id)
            ->willReturn($uniqId);
        $repo = new CountryRepository($country);
        $this->assertSame($uniqId, $repo->getWithoutCitiesById($id), 'Метод возвращает результат вызова find');
    }

}
```

Довольно бестолковый тест. Но он проверяет именно код вашего метода (как и положено юнит-тесту). Если надо проверять сработает ли вся связка так как вы ожидаете, то это уже не юнит-тестирование.

Comment: Спасибо, я так понимаю, если тестировать репозиторий целиком - то это уже фунциональное тестирование. Пусть будет таковым... но вопрос тогда остается открытым. Как проверять? Например метод репозитория insert. Проверять обычной проверкой записи в БД?

Comment: Если уйти от Элоки, представим что есть репозиторий, который надо оттестировать, он может работать как с БД, так и с Api . Как правильно будет делать проверку?

Comment: ORM-то, наверное, протестирована разработчиками. Проверять что работает инсёрт непосредственно в базу, в таком случае, довольно странно. Проверки должны быть типа: если слой работы с бд (апи) вернёт такой-то результат, репозиторий поведёт себя так-то.

Comment: Если хотите функциональный тест, то ответ Игоря вам подходит. Для апи можно сделать что-то подобное. Например, можно поднять мок-сервер (мне нравится такой https://hub.docker.com/r/jordimartin/mmock/). Но как и в случае с бд, такой подход гораздо требовательнее к ресурсам.